# Display alternate row color in data grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Could someone help with a quick alternate way to jquery to display alternate rows with different background colors? Trying with a foreach loop but not having much luck.  Many thanks!!!

```
    <div class="acgridhdrstart">Account Name</div>
<div class="acgridhdr">Account Region</div>
<div class="acgridhdr">Account Representative</div>
<div class="acgridhdr">Peer Partner</div>
<div class="acgridhdr">Last Updated</div>
@while (myreader.Read())
{
<div class="bgcol">
 <span class="acgridstart">@myreader["acname"]</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@myreader["acregion"]</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@myreader["acrep"]</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@myreader["acpeer"]</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@myreader["lastupdated"]</span>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure I'm parsing the question correctly, you don't want to use jQuery?  If not, may I ask why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using SQLDataAdapter and returned the data as follows:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string rowclass = "bgcol";
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        rowclass = "bgalt";
        }
        else
        {
            rowclass = "bgcol";
        }   
<div class="@rowclass">
 <span class="acgridstart">@dt.Rows[i]["acname"].ToString()</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@dt.Rows[i]["acregion"].ToString()</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@dt.Rows[i]["acrep"].ToString()</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@dt.Rows[i]["acpeer"].ToString()</span>
 <span class="acgrid">@dt.Rows[i]["lastupdated"].ToString()</span>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With CSS3 you can :nth-child(even) and :nth-child(odd)

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

jQuery version, FWIW:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

If you want it in the view code, Phil Haack's Cycle method might be useful

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/07/aspnetmvc_cycle.aspx

On the off chance you don't know about it, WebGrid has rowStyle and alternatingRowStyle

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.gethtml(v=vs.99).aspx

Comment: James, thanks for taking the time to write such a comprehensive answer!  I went with a different solution, below, and gave you an upvote :-).

Answer (score 1):

If you can write each rows markup with either an "even" or "odd" class then you can use CSS easily to achieve this effect.  Otherwise, you'll need to use something like jQuery to add the appropriate "even" and "odd" class that correspond to your stripe styles.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#yourtable tr:odd').css('background-color', '#cccccc');
    });
</script>
```